# Why does Lambda need permissions to complete lifecycle hooks?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam

From the AWS [tutorial page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/tutorial-lifecycle-hook-lambda.html) on configuring a lifecycle hook:

> Before you create a Lambda function, you must first create an
> execution role and a permissions policy to allow Lambda to complete
> lifecycle hooks.

What is risky or special about completing lifecycle hooks that permissions are needed?

I can't see what is qualitatively different from anything else we configure in EC2. Everything is risky, but we don't need to set roles and permissions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"completing lifecycle hooks" is actually an **API call** that your lambda should execute against your ASG:

- [complete_lifecycle_action](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/autoscaling.html#AutoScaling.Client.complete_lifecycle_action) - Completes the lifecycle action for the specified token or instance with the specified result.

So your lambda execution role **must have permissions** to perform such an action. For example:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "autoscaling:CompleteLifecycleAction",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```